# EF7 Code First - Property cannot exist on entity type 'object' when generating migration

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

## Problem

When trying to create a initial migration of my EF7 Code First database by executing from the command line:

```
dnx ef migrations add Initial
```

I get the error:

System.InvalidOperationException: The property 'ExerciseTemplateId' cannot exist on entity type 'object' because the property is not marked as shadow state and no corresponding CLR property exists on the underlying type.
[Full Stacktrace](https://gist.github.com/tdshipley/5c9269f20a5b72b71247)

Any ideas?

### The Model Causing the Error

For some reason EF7 doesn't seem to like the primary key property *ExerciseTemplateId* on my Model:

```
public class ExerciseTemplate
{
    public int ExerciseTemplateId { get; set; }
    public string InitalCode { get; set; }
    public string ClassName { get; set; }
    public string MainMethodName { get; set; }

    public int ExerciseForeignKey { get; set; }
    public Exercise Exercise { get; set; }
}
```

### More Detail

The only interesting part of the ExerciseTemplate model is a *one to one* relationship with the Exercise model:

```
public class Exercise
{
    public int ExerciseId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Guidance { get; set; }
    public ExerciseTemplate Template { get; set; }
    public List<ExerciseCategory> Categories { get; set; }
    public List<Test> Tests { get; set; }
}
```

This question is already long so my DBContext is in this [DBContext Gist](https://gist.github.com/tdshipley/2a838456a31cb6361893)

## Update

All the Models and the DB Context can be found at this [Models and Context Gist](https://gist.github.com/tdshipley/27745979b990f0b890f3)

Comment: In a one to (optional) one relation, the dependent entity would have its primary key column also as foreign key column, so you may run into some problems with both a primary key and a foreign key property...

Comment: Sorry not sure I understand. Are you saying that the key property name on ExerciseTemplate shouldn't be there? The docs say you should include a foreign key property in the optional relation. https://ef.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modeling/relationships.html#one-to-one

Comment: Well seems like thats not the problem here (I had something along this path in earlier EF versions). Tested the part of your model that you provided (`Excercise`, `ExerciseTemplate`, `CodingMonkeyContext` with removed references to `ExcerciseCategory` and `Tests`) and it worked. So the error seems to be with parts that you didnt provide with your question yet. Be sure to provide a complete example that reproduces your problem.

Comment: By the way: I tested in the package manager console, not in some external command line.

Comment: Ah ok - I am just using an external command line. Although that shouldn't make a diff should it? I will update my answer with all my models. Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: I have updated the answer with a link at the bottom - sorry its one massive gist! But its at least mostly model classes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107062/discussion-between-grek40-and-tom).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long story short: do not use `object` or `Type` as property type in your model classes. It has no representation in the database.

If you absolutely need to store arbitrary objects, you may use some serializer and store the serialized objects as BLOB in the database.